# Different NServiceBus Serializers for different sources

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I have a process which listens to messages from two publishers.

One publisher uses the default `XmlSerializer` and the other uses a `BinarySerializer`.

Is there any way to be able to recieve messages from both providers in the same process?

As expected setting both serializers in the config causes explosions...

```
Configure.With()
    ...
    .XmlSerializer()
    .BinarySerializer()
    ...
```

Comment: You're out of luck. NSB v4 does not support multiple serializers see https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/736

Comment: More of a discussion but I have been wondering about whether it should really even be possible to switch out a serializer.  In the greater scheme of things, is there any significant performance difference that you have picked up?  Could we not regard the serialization as an infrastructure concern that the service bus should handle as it is simply to transport the message?  Just a thought and I'd like your opinion, seeing as you have this scenario :)

Comment: What version of NSB are you on?(4.4 has a new pipeline that would allow you to get this done)

Comment: @AndreasÖhlund Im running 3.3.8 but we are planning to upgrade to 4 at some stage soon

Comment: Cool, I'll try to get a snippet up that shows how this can be done!